# Cyclic Coordinate Search Algorithm

Tags: r, arrays, algorithm

I have trouble in writing cyclic coordinate search algorithm.

```
ccsfinal <- function(x, alpha, e, Errortolarence, f) {
  k <- 0
  alpha[1] <- 2
  repeat {
    for (j in 1:10) {
      alpha[j] <- which.min(f(x[k] + (alpha[j]*e[j])))
      x[k + 1] <- x[k] + alpha[j]*e[k]
    }
    k <- k + 1
    if (abs(x[k] - x[k - 1]) < Errortolerance) {
      return(x[k])
    }
  }
}
```

I try to work that algorithm with the variables:

```
ccsfinal(c(5, 5), 2, c(2, 2), 1e-5, realf)

realf <- function(x) {
  (5*x[1] - x[2])^4 + (x[1] - 2)^2 + x[1] - 2*x[2] + 12
}
```

Where is my mistake anyone can help me?

Comment: In `f(x[k] + (alpha[j]*e[j]))` you're subsetting `x` with `k=0` which yields `numeric(0)`, hence RHS has length zero.

Comment: How can I solve that? I am really newbie in R :/

Comment: Either `k <- 1` or `k <- 2`  would work, because input `x = c(5, 5)`, however I have no clue what your function does :)

Comment: That gives same error:/

Comment: Probably because e.g. `f(x[1] + (alpha[j]*e[j])` gives `NA`, and `which.min(f(x[k] + (alpha[j]*e[j])))` again `integer(0)`.

Comment: Have you tried `x=c(5, 5);alpha=2;e=c(2, 2);Errortolarence=1e-5;f=realf`and debug function body line by line? Just increase `j` by hand.

Comment: I tried but  gives error at       alpha[j] <- which.min(f(x[k] + (alpha[j]*e[j])))